# jQuery toggleClass - Only working with the first ID selector

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

I would like to create one of those read more / read less buttons using toggleClass().

This is my html:

```
<p>Lots of bla bla bla.....<span id="plus">Plus</span></p>

<p>Lots of bla bla bla.....<span id="plus">Plus</span></p>

<p>Lots of bla bla bla.....<span id="plus">Plus</span></p>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){

     $("#plus").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass( "showmore" );
        var txt = $("p").hasClass("showmore") ? 'Minus' : 'Plus';
        $("#plus").text(txt);
    });

});
```

Fiddle:
[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/William3780/82np6c6d/)

My Question:

How do I get toggleClass to work with multiple IDs (same selectors).   The current script only works with the first ID.

Looking forward to your input, cheers!

Comment: `id` **must** be _unique_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs should be unique. You can rather use same class name

```
<p>Lots of bla bla bla.....<span class="plus">Plus</span></p>

<p>Lots of bla bla bla.....<span class="plus">Plus</span></p>

<p>Lots of bla bla bla.....<span class="plus">Plus</span></p>
```

and then use class selector to target them. also you need to use context `this` in click event to target current element and parent p element with jquery method `.parent()`:

```
$(".plus").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass( "showmore" );
    var txt = $(this).parent().hasClass("showmore") ? 'Minus' : 'Plus';
    $(this).text(txt);
});
```